# Spring Web Flow... how to stop Form Validation on only one transition

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Spring Web Flow... how to stop Form Validation on only one transition.

How to stop Form Validation on only one transition. With the following code I have form validation turn on and everything is working great but if the user clicks "cancel" I dont want to run the form validation. anyway around this?

```
<view-state id="helloworld" view="input.jsp" model="customer" popup="true">
<transition on="submit" to="preview" />
<transition on="cancel" to="thanks"/>
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transitions have the ability to define whether or not you want binding and validation, just set them to false.

```
<view-state id="helloworld" view="input.jsp" model="customer" popup="true">
<transition on="submit" to="preview" />
<transition on="cancel" to="thanks" validate="false" bind="false"/>
</view-state>
```

Comment: you dont need the bind="false" just the validate="false"

Comment: You often want `bind="false"` when you use `validate="false"`, though. Otherwise your model object accepts data that was never checked.

Comment: @dbreaux Agreed. I always follow this idiom as well.